# Why is `ScrollView.scrollTo()` is not working on android?

Tags: android, react-native

**tldr;** I want a simple ScrollView with some items and something like a TableOfContents that when pressed can scroll to one of the items in the ScrollView

##### Background

I have a very simple ScrollView with multiple Views.

```
const scrollRef = useRef<ScrollView>(null);
const items = {[id: 0, ...], [id: 1, ...], [id: 2, ...], ..., [id: n, ...]}
const refs = items.map(() => useRef<View>(null))

<ScrollView ref={scrollRef}>
    {items.map((item, i) => (
        <View ref=[refs[i]] {...item}>...</View>
    )}
</ScrollView>
```

I want to add `scrollTo` functionality to that list.
I have learned that there is no `scrollRef.current.scrollTo(ref)` method but there is `scrollRef.current.scrollTo({ y })`. This reduces the problem to calculating each View's y position in the ScrollView.

What I have tried

##### Approach 1: `ref.measure()`

added a call to `ref.current.measure` on a button's `onPress()`. However, it returns `{y: undefinded}` For all views. Even the one's within the *focus*. And this is only for Android, works as it should on iOS.

##### Approach 2: `onLayout`

Created a new state, `viewDimensions` and update on the view's `onLayout`

```
const [viewLocations, setViewLocations] = useState<Record, number>({})

...

<ScrollView ref={scrollRef}>
    {items.map((item, i) => (
        <View ref=[refs[i]] onLayout={(e) => {
            setViewLocations(prev => ({...prev, [item.id]: e.nativeEvent.layout.y}))
        }} {...item}>
        ...
        </View>
    )}
</ScrollView>
```

The problem with this is performance, it works fine with 10 items. But when 100 items are used the app is not usable with everything happening in the background.

##### Question

Is there a 3rd approach I am not aware of? Or an adjustment to the previous approaches to make them usable for both Android and iOS?

Comment: Maybe FlatList and scrollToIndex would work.